# Gradle task while init db

Tags: gradle

```
task initdb() {
    doLast {// Make sure the code is run during execution phase and not configuration phase
        def dbUrl = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.31.0.50:1521/FCJ12PROD'
        def dbUsername = 'iba_app'
        def dbPassword = 'iba_app'
        def dbDriver = 'oracle.driver.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword, dbDriver)
    }
}
```

Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

> Task :initdb FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\CodesIBAR\chasis\build.gradle' line: 220
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':initdb'.

> Could not set unknown property 'dbDriver' for task ':initdb' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Variables in Groovy need to be defined with either `def` (like you did for the `sql` variable), or a type. Also, next time, try formulating your problem as a question and briefly describe what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I have tried by adding def, still the same error.  I am trying to dynamic building a gradle.script, by customize tasks

Comment: Are you sure you are still getting the same error? Perhaps you forgot to save the script before running it again? When I try, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.driver.jdbc.OracleDriver`, which is expected as this is what you have in the connection string. But that is another problem.